# Console Vim doesn't render bold and italic text

Tags: vim

For some reasons, my vim totally doesn't want to render bold and italic text, so i don't know what to do. I use solarized colorscheme, xfce4-terminal and Xubuntu 20.04 OS.

[image: Vim not rendering italics and bold]

Comment: This question doesn't belong here as it is not related to programming. Better to ask it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) as root cause is likely misconfigured terminal emulator and/or Vim itself.

Comment: Some terminal emulators dont support bold/italics. Try a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems half of the year have passed, but i find solution only now. There's one useful command `:hi[ghlight] {group-name} {key}={arg}`. Information about group-names, keys and args outputs by :hi in vim. For example, if i wanna make functions to be bold i just input next command:

```
:hi Function cterm=bold
```

cterm variable changes text view in console vim (i tested it in konsole and xfce-terminal, so i guess it's also useful for gnome terminal). I also tried to output comments with italic style with `hi Comment cterm=italic`, but some terminals doesn't support italics. You can check it with `echo -e "\e[3m is this italics? \e[23m"`. I guess case's closed=)